# I can ping from my PC to VM on ubuntu but not the way around

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine

I have installed ubuntu 12.04 on Windows 7. I can ping ubuntu VM from my desktop but not the way around. I have disabled firewall both on desktop and VM & I have enabled icmpv4. On VM I can ping the local networks. Please assist using the attached info.

[image: PC_IP]

[image: VM_IP]

Comment: Some description of the problem would be helpful. What happens when you try to ping the other way? Does the packet go out? Do you get the correct ARP entries? Does it get received? Is a reply sent? (I presume a reply is not received.)

Comment: You do know these ping results don't tell us a damned thing if we don't know what address belongs to which computer and from which one you are pinging right?

Also, you need to share what connection setup is used on the virtual machine (how is the network stack configured in your virtual machine software, and which virtual machine software are you using?)

Comment: the network is on bridge mode, where i assigned the static ip 192.168.70.8/24 on vm and pc is 192.168.70.2/24. The error is destination host unreachable when i ping from VM to PC. The above images where performed on PC